# Objective-C —textfield to string array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have this and it works:

```
[pole insertObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[textfield text]] atIndex:idpole];
```

But this doesn't save to string what is in the texfield, but some numbers or other unspecified characters. What can I do, to save real text from a textfield?

Comment: can you give an example of the text that will be in the field and the output you want?

Comment: Don't use +stringWithFormat: when you don't need to.  Parsing a format string is expensive.  Just use [[[textfield text] copy] autorelease]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[pole insertObject:[textfield text] atIndex:idpole];
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to create a new string:

```
[pole insertObject: [textfield text] atIndex:idpole];
```

Or if you want to make sure the the string a new object:

```
[pole insertObject: [NSString stringWithString:[textfield text]] atIndex:idpole];
```

Comment: Even if there is no need to create a new NSString, could you tell us why his code does not work ?

Comment: Yes,  %s is expecting a cstring not NSString. If you want to use a NSString in a formet use %@

Answer (score 1):

Thats because [textfield text] is a reference to a NSString object.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Answer (score 1):

```
[pole insertObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[textfield text]] atIndex:idpole];

    NSlog(@"%@",pole);
```